# Using IP restricting API's on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, ip

A third party API that we are using restricts access based on IP address. Since there is no dedicated IP for a heroku app, what is the optimal solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get another server that you can control the IP on (like an EC2 instance) and then route your requests through that.

Or, talk with the API provider about modifying their access controls.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new Heroku addon called Proximo designed to solve this problem:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo